# Why does TextBox Border Colour insist on and not changing in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, styles

As far as I understand I should be using Style triggers to update the TextBox's border colour when it is focused. However no matter what I do it always turns to the system default blue, not the black I have specified.

Anyone have any ideas?

Code below:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Try using IsKeyboardFocusWithin

Comment: @DanTonyBrown, `TextBox` has its default template which will overwrite `BorderBrush` colour when focused

Comment: @dowhilefor Unfortunately that didn't work :/

Comment: @dkozl How would you get around that?

Comment: Have a look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068(v=vs.110).aspx) and overide the styles.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try set for `BorderThickness` value more than `1` (by default):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Pink" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBox Width="100"
             Height="30"
             Text="Test" 
             BorderThickness="4" />
</Grid>
```

Tested on Windows Seven.

**`Edit: why is this happening?`**

I looked in the default style for `TextBox` in Blend under Windows 7, here it is ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
    </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome>

    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Here there is two parameters:

```
RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}"
```

They are responsible for blue gradient Border when states `Focus` and `MouseOver` and probably there stands a condition on `BorderThickness` and `BorderBrush`. If they *`remove / reset`* the blue gradient Border will disappear and will not need to set values for `BorderThickness` greater than 1.

In *`ILSpy`* I found `ChangeVisualState(bool)` method in TextBoxBase class, here it is:

```
internal override void ChangeVisualState(bool useTransitions)
{
    if (!base.IsEnabled)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Disabled", useTransitions);
    }
    else
    {
        if (this.IsReadOnly)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "ReadOnly", useTransitions);
        }
        else
        {
            if (base.IsMouseOver)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "MouseOver", useTransitions);
            }
            else
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Normal", useTransitions);
            }
        }
    }

    if (base.IsKeyboardFocused)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Focused", useTransitions);
    }
    else
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Unfocused", useTransitions);
    }

    base.ChangeVisualState(useTransitions);
}
```

It turns out that these visual states implemented "systematically" and in Styles not present.

Comment: A big thank you, not only for the solution (I set my thickness to 1.01, because I only wanted 1px borders) but for mentioning operating system. I was deving on Windows Server 2012... which didn't work. However it did on Windows 7

Comment: @Anatoliy - Does that work? I tried on windows 8 but couldn't get it working.

Comment: @Rohit Vats: I tested under Windows Seven and at me worked. If I'm not mistaken, under XP would work immediately, without setting value more than 1. Unfortunately, under Windows 8 can not test.

Comment: @DanTonyBrown: I'm glad that it worked). But it looks like a hack, and that the solution is stable work you need to look at the answer of Rohit Vats.

Comment: @Rohit Vats: While I can not say for sure, I wanted to ask you :). Possible that the default styles are different for each version Windows?

Comment: @Anatoily - Yeah could be the possible reason because default style for Windows8 is picked from `PresentationFramework.Aero2.dll` and for  Windows7 it's picked from `PresentationFramework.Aero.dll`.

Comment: Was you able to see the `VisualState` of `Focus`?

Comment: @Rohit Vats: Unfortunately, no. Visual states in the Style/Template of TextBox is not present, apparently these states implemented system. The same applies to the `RichTextBox`, there are three states, but for the Focus and MouseOver respond these two parameters: `RenderFocused` and `RenderMouseOver`, in ILSpy I have not found them.

Comment: @Rohit Vats: Okay, I found a `ChangeVisualState` method in TextBoxBase class.

Comment: @Anatoily - That's right dude. It's embedded somewhere inside theme resource file of Aero dll. +1 for taking out time and posting your findings here.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Default template of `TextBox` has **trigger which set the border brush of textBox**. In case you want to override it, you need to **override `ControlTemplate` of TextBox**.

This is how you do that:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
              <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                      Name="border"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                 <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                               VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                               Name="PART_ContentHost"
                               Focusable="False" />
              </Border>
           <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="UIElement.Opacity" TargetName="border"
                        Value="0.56"/>
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border" 
                        Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border" 
                       Value="Black"/> <-- HERE
              </Trigger>
           </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
 </Style>
```

Also you might want to override MouseOver brush to Black in above template. You can do that by supplying color value for `UIElement.IsMouseOver` trigger.